# Importing Go packages locally rather than remotely

Tags: node.js, go, package

In a node.js project, I'm using Go for a critical part of it that node isn't adequate enough to handle. I want to split the Go code into a `sockets` package and a `main` package, with `sockets` containing required structs/interfaces for the `main` package to run. The problem I'm having is that from what I can gather from Go's documentation, I can only use external packages like `sockets` remotely from github/gopkg. I don't want to split the repository for the project into one containing the Go code and one containing node's. How can I make the `sockets` package available for `main` to import locally while making it possible to rebuild the binaries for the two packages if any updates to their source code are made?

Edit: importing the packages is no longer an issue, but rebuilding packages on update still remains

Comment: What do you mean "remotely"? All go source files ought to be in your path, or atleast `GOPATH`

Comment: That was badly worded. I know the packages I pull from github are kept in my `GOPATH`. I was talking about how the directories within `$GOPATH/src/` are named with the github repo the package originated from.

Comment: Read [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).  With the exception of the 'go get' subcommand, all of the Go tools work with local files and care not that a directory name might correspond to a Github or other remote location.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense now. I was confused about how I'd be able to update the packages if the directory the source code is in doesn't correspond to a real github repo, but I'm sure there are other ways to handle updates for my own code besides `go get`

Comment: Use git commands directly when working with your own code and other code that you edit

Comment: I do. What I want to do is automate rebuilding the packages when needed, but I think that can be handled in the launch script I'm using by checking if any of the source files' metadata for when they were last modified has changed or if a hash of the files' contents has changed since the last time the launch script was run. I'm wondering if there are better ways to do this though.

Comment: Have you looked into vendoring?

Comment: I hadn't heard of it before, but it looks like it's exactly what I need! Thanks, I'll leave this open if any of you want to post an answer

Comment: Use the 'go install' command to automatically rebuild your packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens the same to my team too and we end up using vendor it's pretty easy to manage all the external packages. So, whoever checkout your repo will have all the packages inside vendor.

[Understanding and using the vendor folder](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/)

And Please refer this site lots of other option out there too:

[Golang Package Management Tools](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools)